# HP ProLiant DL360 G7 watchdog

Tags: linux, hardware, hp, hp-proliant, watchdog

I have dl360 G7 servers. some times kernel got panic. I understood, that server have hardware watchdog timer.

`dmesg | grep wdt
[    6.344992] hpwdt 0000:02:00.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 16 (level, low) -> IRQ 16
[    6.345563] hpwdt: New timer passed in is 30 seconds.`

Server already is in production. Question is: how i can enable it? Did i need some software to install on system too? On server is running debian. 
I understood that i need on system some software that tells watchdog, that system is alive. Or i am wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [watchdog timer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watchdog_timer) in this context resets the system or takes some action if it loses a "pulse". HP ProLiant servers have a hardware watchdog that ties into the [Automatic Server Recovery (ASR)](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?objectID=c01158873&lang=en&cc=us&taskId=101&prodSeriesId=428936) feature. The ASR reboots the server if it detects a hang lasting a certain period of time (default is 10 minutes).

On your Debian system, the hpwdt == [HP Watchdog Timer](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/watchdog/hpwdt.txt). This is a kernel module. Instructions for its use are contained within  the [kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/watchdog/hpwdt.txt).

Comment: when i enable ASR, then i need to configure some software? Or kernel by default knows answers to ASR questions ?

Comment: You won't need to make any software changes.